# get group details by group id in azure ad not returns correctly

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Microsoft Graph API. I have around 200 azure active directory groups and I tried to get the group details using the group ids as shown below.

```
foreach($arrayReq as $key=>$value){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/".$value,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                                    "Authorization: Bearer <authorization-token>",
                                    "Content-Type: application/json"
                    ),
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $arrayRes[]=$result;
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
}
var_dump($arrayRes);exit();
```

I'm getting the below response randomly for some of the groups.

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>No Root configuration found at: Root</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red '...
```

How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the curl, but can you please confirm the URL is formed as `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<<GUID of group>>`? Also, you can check the network trace using fiddler to see the sent request.

Comment: Is it specific groups that regularly fail or does calling a given group multiple times result in a random result?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur no it's happening randomly.